# MIP SDK Java Wrapper Sample Fails to Start

Tags: java, microsoft-information-protection

I'm trying to start the sample program packaged with the MIP SDK Java Wrapper 1.8.86 on an amd64 Windows machine.

I've copied the `mip_java.dll` to the sdk directory as instructed, added the absolute path to the `file/bins/release/amd64` directory to the front of the `java.library.path` system property and replaced the null argument in `MIP#initialize` with the same path. Then, I started the program.

The result was:

```
Can't load <...>\file\bins\release\amd64\mip_file_sdk.dll . Error was:<...>\file\bins\release\amd64\mip_file_sdk.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

So I analyzed the dependencies with [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) which found all dependencies on my machine.
I then proceeded to load each dependency manually using `System#loadLibrary` until I got the following error:

```
<...>\file\bins\release\amd64\libgmodule-2.0-0.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
```

*(translated from German "Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden")*

Any idea what I should try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using debug or release mode?

There's a bug in the current Java SDK that requires all of the DLLs from the SDK to be copied to the root path of the project. I expect we'll fix that in 1.9.

You can try to pull this project and see if it works. You'll need to copy all of the SDK DLLs from 1.8.97 to the project root and run it.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mipsdk-filesdk-java-sample

Comment: I'm using the release mode.
When I copied the DLLs to the root folder it worked as expected. Thank you!